# cython: both const and except in C++ method declaration

Tags: cython

My code is:

```
cdef extern from "mylib.h":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        MyClass(const char *data) except +
        # and I also need except + for myMethod
        int myMethod(size_t len, char *data) const
```

I need both `const` and `except +` for my method, but I cannot.  I tried to write it after space, after comma, put both declarations in parenthes -- but got different types of cyntax errors.  Documentation gave no hints about multiple annotations...

cython 0.20.1 from Ubuntu Trusty was used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, the answer the OP seems to have got from the Cython [mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.user/12281) was essentially that it is currently not possible, but that it might not matter in practice, since the `const` can be dropped in favour of the `except +` without affecting the ability to compile.

Comment: But it does make a difference if you put the C++ part in a separate shared library, it seems. It then can't find the required symbol.